# Python 3 debug in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: netbeans

I use netbeans as my main IDE. Today I want to program a few small things with python. I installed the python plugin for netbeans and used nbpython to debug, but this nbpython plugin uses python 2 but my code writes on python 3.

My question:

- Can I fix for debug with python 3?
- Is there any plugin that supports python code on netbeans?

I tried to cover the entire code in the plugin folder nbpython debug using 2to3 in hopes of debugging with python 3 but encountered some errors like

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sins/.netbeans/8.1rc/config/nbPython/debug/nbpythondebug/jpydaemon.py", line 59, in <module>
    from. import dbgutils
Debug session Abort = 1`

Obviously this is a bad idea

Note: Because I only write a few small tools, I do not want to use full-featured IDEs for python like pycharm.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all,

Careless for my shortcomings. This is the solution for this bug. (It seems to cover the source code from python 2 to python3). my idea. hehe
Solution: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=253868

Thanks you.